# How to align 'implies that' symbols neatly in equation array

Tags: align

The following is an equation array I have:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\Rightarrow\eta_t &=& \eta_x(\omega \eta-(\varphi_x)_s) + (\varphi_y)_s\notag\\
\Rightarrow\eta_t\,(\varphi_y)_s &=& \eta_x(\omega \eta-(\varphi_x)_s)(\varphi_y)_s +      {(\varphi_y)_s}^2\notag\\
&=&\omega\, \eta\,(\varphi_y)_s\, \eta_x-(\varphi_x)_s\, \eta_x(\varphi_y)_s +     {(\varphi_y)_s}^2.
\end{eqnarray}
```

All I want to do is move the first 'implies that' symbol so that it is aligned with the second one and to not change anything else. I have tried several things but the end result is always that the equations are stretched out and I want to avoid that. (I know use of eqnarray is not recommended but I've done too much to go back and change everything!!)

Comment: Never ever use `eqnarray`; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/4427) and the links in it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that you only need two alignment points. (Also, [Avoid `eqnarray`!](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf).)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  &\Rightarrow\quad
  &\eta_{t}
  &= \eta_{x}(\omega\eta - (\varphi_{x})_{s}) + (\varphi_{y})_{s}\notag\\ 
  &\Rightarrow
  &\eta_t(\varphi_{y})_{s}
  &= \eta_{x}(\omega\eta - (\varphi_{x})_{s})(\varphi_{y})_{s} + {(\varphi_{y})_{s}}^{2}\notag\\  
  &&&= \omega\eta(\varphi_{y})_{s}\eta_{x} - (\varphi_{x})_{s}\eta_{x}(\varphi_{y})_{s} + {(\varphi_{y})_{s}}^{2}. 
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Update**

I think you have one arrow too many. Either way, here are one version with a single *horizontal* arrow and another version with a single *vertical* arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  &&\eta_{t}
  &= \eta_{x}(\omega\eta - (\varphi_{x})_{s}) + (\varphi_{y})_{s}\notag\\
  &\Rightarrow\quad
  &\eta_t(\varphi_{y})_{s}
  &= \eta_{x}(\omega\eta - (\varphi_{x})_{s})(\varphi_{y})_{s} + {(\varphi_{y})_{s}}^{2}\notag\\  
  &&&= \omega\eta(\varphi_{y})_{s}\eta_{x} - (\varphi_{x})_{s}\eta_{x}(\varphi_{y})_{s} + {(\varphi_{y})_{s}}^{2}. 
\end{alignat}
or
\begin{alignat}{2}
  &&\eta_{t}
  &= \eta_{x}(\omega\eta - (\varphi_{x})_{s}) + (\varphi_{y})_{s}\notag\\
  \ArrowBetweenLines[\Downarrow]
  &&\eta_t(\varphi_{y})_{s}
  &= \eta_{x}(\omega\eta - (\varphi_{x})_{s})(\varphi_{y})_{s} + {(\varphi_{y})_{s}}^{2}\notag\\
  &&&= \omega\eta(\varphi_{y})_{s}\eta_{x} - (\varphi_{x})_{s}\eta_{x}(\varphi_{y})_{s} + {(\varphi_{y})_{s}}^{2}.
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Answer (score 8):

Given that you are using `\notag` you must have loaded the [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.  In that case, you may well have seen that the `amsmath` environments are to be strongly preferred over `eqnarray`. In this case you can use `alignat`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
  \Rightarrow&\quad&
  \eta_t &= \eta_x(\omega \eta-(\varphi_x)_s) + (\varphi_y)_s\notag\\ 
  \Rightarrow&&
  \eta_t\,(\varphi_y)_s &= \eta_x(\omega
    \eta-(\varphi_x)_s)(\varphi_y)_s + {(\varphi_y)_s}^2\notag\\  
  &&&=\omega\, \eta\,(\varphi_y)_s\, \eta_x-(\varphi_x)_s\,
    \eta_x(\varphi_y)_s + {(\varphi_y)_s}^2. 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

An alternative is to use the [`eqnarray`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eqnarray) package and its `equationarray` environment, where you can specify alignment of columns and get a syntax much as in `eqnarray`:

[image: equationarry sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqnarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{equationarray}{rrcl}
  \Rightarrow&
  \eta_t &=& \eta_x(\omega \eta-(\varphi_x)_s) + (\varphi_y)_s\notag\\ 
  \Rightarrow&
  \eta_t\,(\varphi_y)_s &=& \eta_x(\omega
    \eta-(\varphi_x)_s)(\varphi_y)_s + {(\varphi_y)_s}^2\notag\\  
  &&=&\omega\, \eta\,(\varphi_y)_s\, \eta_x-(\varphi_x)_s\,
    \eta_x(\varphi_y)_s + {(\varphi_y)_s}^2. 
\end{equationarray}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Avoid `eqnarray`; it produces awful spacing. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/4427) and the links in it titled “Avoid eqnarray!”.

If you want a unique equation number, I suggest to use `alignedat` inside `equation`, which will vertically center the equation number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
\Rightarrow\quad &&
  \eta_t                &= \eta_x(\omega \eta-(\varphi_x)_s) + (\varphi_y)_s
\\
\Rightarrow\quad &&
  \eta_t\,(\varphi_y)_s &= \eta_x(\omega \eta-(\varphi_x)_s)(\varphi_y)_s+(\varphi_y)_s^2
\\
&&
                        &= \omega\eta(\varphi_y)_s\eta_x-(\varphi_x)_s\eta_x(\varphi_y)_s+(\varphi_y)_s^2.    
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some points to note.

1. There's no need of `\,` in the last line
2. Typing `{(\varphi_x)_s}^2` sets the exponent like it was hanging from nowhere. I'd simply use `(\varphi_x)_s^2` that's clear as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a TABstack.  The interline gap can be set with the commented out `\setstackgap{S}{}` line (default 3pt).  The gap to the right of the `\Rightarrow` can be set with the commented out `\setstackaligngap` line (default 1em = `\quad`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
%\setstackgap{S}{3pt}
%\setstackaligngap{1em}
\alignShortstack{
\Rightarrow&&\eta_t =& \eta_x(\omega \eta-(\varphi_x)_s) +
(\varphi_y)_s\\
\Rightarrow&&\eta_t\,(\varphi_y)_s =& \eta_x(\omega
\eta-(\varphi_x)_s)(\varphi_y)_s +      {(\varphi_y)_s}^2\\
&&=&\omega\, \eta\,(\varphi_y)_s\, \eta_x-(\varphi_x)_s\,
\eta_x(\varphi_y)_s +     {(\varphi_y)_s}^2.
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]